# Micro Resetting

Tags: microcontroller, noise, emi-filtering

I am working on a new design. Intermittently, when I close SW1 or SW2, the micro will reset. I've scoped it and have attached the image. I see there is noise on the 5VDC power supply. Am looking for input as to how I can eliminate this noise.
My thoughts as of right now would be:
• Snubber on K1 and K5 coils
• Larger C21
• Larger C16

On the next round of this module, I will device a means of staging K1 and K5 as I believe the fact that they're being energized at the same time is the problem.

Thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are there any decoupling caps near the ULN and the connected relays?

Comment: What do you mean by near them? Physically located near?

Comment: physically near with short leads. You want the loop relay coil, ULN and capacitor al small as possible

Comment: Does that ripple also occur at the V+? Maybe try a 100nF at the input of U9? Does the problem stil occur when you a) remove the relai coils, or b) replace them with compareable resistors?

Comment: I am not seeing this noise on V+. It is solid. Will try your thoughts on removing the relays and replacing with resistors. What is your thinking there? too much current through pull up resistors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without doubt one of the main problems is the massive impulse of current taken when a switch closes - it charges a 47uF up to about 33V and it does this with a big splash of current and this current "returns" through the 0V connections of the MCU. You would have to be really careful on how you layed out the PCB to avoid this current (maybe tens of amps) upsetting a micro. If you have it on breadboard it will be a nightmare.

Try putting a 1k resistor in series with each switch to prove me wrong or right. It could be something else but I've seen this exact thing happen a few times.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for a solution to this? I am considering removing the relay coils from V+ and using the 24VAC with diode & cap to provide + reference for the coil. Then continue switching the low side via ULN. Have not tried this yet

Comment: Read my final paragraph

Comment: If I place a 1kΩ resistor in series with the relay coil, it will not pull in. Too large a voltage drop across the relay. I tried a 240Ω and am still experiencing reset issues.  Please clarify the 100uF comment. Thank you for the suggestions

Comment: @becjasl what are you talking about - I said place it in series with the switch!!!!!

Comment: @WillDean ooh yeah baby!!!

Comment: I see the ULN as the switch, which is in series with the coil. You talking about SW1 / SW2?

Comment: @becjasl I see no other switches, yes.

Comment: @becjasl The issue is that before sw1 or 2 closes, the 47 and 100 caps will be discharged, and so look like a short circuit, or very near, to ground.  When the switch closes, you put about 23v across this, which will cause a huge current to flow.

Comment: I was so focused on K1 and K5 as being the source of the problem, I totally misread what you were suggesting. Sorry about that. Placed a 1kΩ as suggested and seems much more stable. Lesson learned